# Resource missing error: Can't upgrade a plan on Stripe

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-functions, stripe-payments

I'd like to use Stripe Billing to implement the feature that allows the users to upgrade their plan in a subscription business. The users already are members of the free plan. It requires 2 steps.

1) Register their credit card

```
stripe.paymentMethods.attach(
  paymentMethodId,
  { customer: customerId }
)
```

2) Upgrade a subscription plan

```
  stripe.subscriptions.update(subscriptionId, {
    cancel_at_period_end: false,
    proration_behavior: 'create_prorations',
    items: [{
      id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
      plan: planId,
    }]
  })
```

I could have passed 1). But the issue occurs in 2).

The error:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "resource_missing",
    "doc_url": "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/resource-missing",
    "message": "This customer has no attached payment source or default payment method.",
    "type": "invalid_request_error"
  }
}
```

How can I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After attaching the PaymentMethod to the Customer you need to register it as the default payment method for the subscription. There are two ways to do this.

You can register the PaymentMethod as the default payment method in the Customer's invoice settings:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/customers/update?lang=node#update_customer-invoice_settings-default_payment_method

```
// add this after attaching the PaymentMethod to the Customer
// (i.e, this won't work unless the PaymentMethod is attached to the Customer)

await stripe.customers.update(customerId, {
  invoice_settings: {
    default_payment_method: paymentMethodId,
  },
});
```

When the customer subscribes to a paid plan they will be charged to this payment method by default.

The second option is to set the default payment method on the subscription itself:

https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create?lang=node#create_subscription-default_payment_method

```
// add this after attaching the PaymentMethod to the Customer

stripe.subscriptions.update(subscriptionId, {
  default_payment_method: paymentMethodId,
  cancel_at_period_end: false,
  proration_behavior: 'create_prorations',
  items: [{
    id: subscription.items.data[0].id,
    plan: planId,
  }]
})
```

The main difference between these two approaches is that if you go with the second approach (adding the default payment method to the subscription) you will have to do the same for any future subscriptions created for that customer. On the other hand, if you save the payment method as the default under the customer's invoice settings then that payment method will be used by default on any future subscriptions without you having to do anything.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yeah, I've completely done it :)